# unix - find unmatch of lines in 2 text file

Tags: unix, awk, grep, diff, comm

Im trying to do match and unmatch practice..I did try try grep and diff... but it only match for whole line.... is it possible to match the lines in file likes below?

If I have 2 files:

file 1:

```
cat_cute    
green_apple_sour    
red_bean_big    
red_pepper_three    
ginger_yellow
```

file 2:

```
cat    
green_apple    
red_pepper    
papaya
```

Output:

```
(file1)
red_bean_big    
ginger_yellow            
(file2)    
papaya
```

I had success try with method below before I post this question. I apologize for not listing this in my first post.
I set file 2 as target match. For file 1, I use TCL to remove all the unwanted adjectives. Then I get new file 1

newfile 1:

```
cat    
green_apple    
red_bean    
red_pepper    
ginger
```

then I applied:

```
grep -Fxvf newfile1 file2
```

I get the output I want.

I just wondering is it there is other way to use only the grep command without the TCL regsub process. I did try awk, comm and grep. It only match when the whole line is match 100%.

Thank you.

Comment: If in file1 there is a line `dogs_eat_papaya` , should this line appear in output?

Comment: `grep -v -f file2 file1` seems to be all you need.

Comment: No... just exactly match the front only.

Comment: so assume the back can be any number. dog1  dog56 dog135 in my file 1; dog in file2. is it possible having output : all match. ?

Comment: I've voted to close this question because it appears to be a request for a recommendation for a tool or solution, rather than a request for assistance with your own code. This makes your question off-topic for StackOverflow. If that assessment was incorrect, and you do indeed want help writing your own code, then please [add your work so far to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45134616/edit) and I'll retract my close vote.

Comment: I'm sorry as my question is not clear enough, I'm here not seeking for solution. Okay, I did try successfully with after I using TCL and greb  regsub [0-9]+ with "", then the

Answer (score 0):

In awk:

```
$ awk '
NR==FNR {                  # first file
    a[$1]                  # hash entries to a
    next                   # next record
}
{                          # second file
    for(i in a)            # for each record go thru the whole of a
        if(i~$1||$1~i) {   # see if there is a match
            delete a[i]    # del if
            next           # and skip to next record
        }                  
    b[$1]                  # else store entry to b
}
END {                      # in the end
    print "(file1)" 
    for(i in a) 
        print i            # output a and
    print "(file2)"
    for(i in b) 
        print i            # b entries
}' file1 file2
(file1)
ginger_yellow
red_bean_big
(file2)
papaya
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand your problem properly. BTW you can do it by `awk` easily.

```
awk -F'_' 'FILENAME=="file2.txt" {a[$1$2]=$1$2} FILENAME=="file1.txt" {if(!(a[$1] || a[$1$2])) {print}}' file2.txt file1.txt
```

It will print:

```
red_bean_big    
ginger_yellow
```

For File2 You can reverse the order(with minor changes).

```
awk -F'_' 'FILENAME=="file1.txt" {a[$1]=$1} FILENAME=="file2.txt" {if(!(a[$1])) {print}}' file1.txt file2.txt
```

Above command will print:

```
papaya
```

I hope I understood your problem clearly. Please comment below if you require something else.